# Method App\Http\Controllers\Controller::create2/{sku} does not exist

Tags: laravel, routes

How to pass a value in the route of laravel, I have tried to pass SKU in the laravel but it's showing me the error.

```
$sku = $request->SKU_code;
return redirect()->route('create.step2',['sku', $sku]);
```

route

```
Route::get('create/step-2', Controller@create2/{sku}')->name('create.step2');
```

Comment: Can you post your web.php or your route? Have you read [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes), especially the section "_Generating URLs To Named Routes_"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass parameter like below:

```
$sku = $request->SKU_code;
return redirect()->route('create.step2',['sku', $sku]);

Route::get('create/step-2/{sku}', 'Controller@create2')->name('create.step2');
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. But still there some error

Comment: @Naren Your route is wrong. I have updated in my answer.

Comment: @kerbholz yes I have forgotten to remove  `'`. right

Comment: You mean you forgot to add one, `Controller@create2` should be `'Controller@create2'`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('create/step-2', Controller@create2/{sku}')->name('create.step2');
```

should be something like:

```
Route::get('create/step-2/{sku}', 'Controller@create2')->name('create.step2');
```